# magento2 how to override model file?

Tags: magento2, module, custom-options

I would like to override (call the below model file from my custom module called Demo_Customprice

```
/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Option/Value.php
```

How could we achieve this?

Comment: You can check with https://webkul.com/blog/overriding-rewriting-classes-magento2/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

in you etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option\Value" type="Demo\Customprice\Model\Rewrite\Catalog\Product\Option\Value" />

</config>
```

in your Model file

```
namespace Demo\Customprice\Model\Rewrite\Catalog\Product\Option;

    class Value extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option\Value
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            echo "Model Rewrite Working"; die();

        }

    }
```

[Reference](http://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento_2/magento-2-overriding-rewriting-model/)

**If use any constant value from interface.**

```
namespace Demo\Customprice\Model\Rewrite\Catalog\Product\Option;

     use Demo\Customprice\Api\Data\AccountInterface;

        class Value extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option\Value
        {
            public function __construct()
            {
                echo "Model Rewrite Working"; die();

            }

        }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getCustomerId() {
        return $this->_getData(AccountInterface::CUSTOMER_ID);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function setCustomerId($customerId) {
        $this->setData(AccountInterface::CUSTOMER_ID, $customerId);

        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Satti thanks for the reply but based on that i am getting errors http://prntscr.com/e90sdy  whether i have to do anything more?

Comment: @NAGARAJUK after seen this error there we problem in you xml kindly check all nodes are closed properly?

Comment: Sure. Let me check and confirm you thanks

Comment: thanks now its loading fine but  how  can i override the public function getPrice($flag = false) function.

Comment: @NAGARAJUK simply add  `public function getPrice($flag = false)
        {
            echo "Model Rewrite Working"; die();

        }`

Comment: yes. i have kept like this but function not calling please refer my code http://prntscr.com/e91z8p

Comment: I'm guessing you resolved this by now? Was it anything to do with the fact your code `die`s at the constructor? That would probably explain why you can't call any functions on the object, if script execution stops at object creation. While it's a good test to see if your model is actually being called, you'll need to remove the __construct method (or at least make it call parent::__construct and not `die`) if you want your other methods to work.

Comment: @DougMcLean this is test code for overriding. off course you have to remove this code make other function work.

Comment: can somebody help for this? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/229781/i-want-to-override-model-in-the-magento-2