# How to display instock product first on the category page in magento 2.1?

Tags: magento-2.1, out-of-stock, category-listing

I want to display In stock products first and out of stock at end of the listing.

I have used below code in `magento/module-catalog/Model`

```
$collection->joinField('stk', 'cataloginventory_stock_item', 'is_in_stock', 'product_id=entity_id', 'qty>=0', 'left')->setOrder('stk','desc');
```

But I am getting the error:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): A joined field with this alias is already declared.
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please never work in the magento folder. Have a look here, how to override models: [magento2 how to override model file?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/160041/magento2-how-to-override-model-file)

In your case i would write probably a plugin for getAttributeUsedForSortByArray() where you add is_in_stock.

Comment: I was working in Magento folder only for testing. I'll override this. Could you please help me to do this task?