# I want to override model in the Magento 2

Tags: magento2, model, override-model

I want to override the **Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\FilterableAttributeList** model file.
I have created the module.
This is my di.xml file.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\FilterableAttributeList" type="Pos\AdvancedLayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Category\FilterableAttributeList" />
</config>
```

This is my model file,

```
<?php
namespace Pos\AdvancedLayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Category;
class FilterableAttributeList extends Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\FilterableAttributeList
{
 public function getList()
    {
     /** @var $collection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\Collection */
        $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
        $collection->setItemObjectClass(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::class)
            ->addStoreLabel($this->storeManager->getStore()->getId())
            ->setOrder('position', 'DESC');
        $collection = $this->_prepareAttributeCollection($collection);
        $collection->load();

        return $collection;
    }
}
```

Can you guys help me!!!!
Is there any way to overwrite this file?

Comment: we can override model using plugin also

Comment: You need to use plugin or observer. You can't override this module.

Comment: @RohanHapani, Can you just guide me how to use plugin for this model? This function (getList()) use for the attribute sorting on the category page.In the magento default sort order is 'ASC'  and i want only change order to DESC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> etc/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\FilterableAttributeList">
        <plugin name="infinity_product_gallery" type="Namespace\Module\Plugin\FilterableAttributeList" />
        </type>
    </config>
```

> Namespace\Module\Plugin\FilterableAttributeList.php

```
<?php
    namespace Namespace\Module\Plugin;

    class FilterableAttributeList 
    {

        protected $collectionFactory;


        protected $storeManager;

        /**
         * FilterableAttributeList constructor
         *
         * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
         * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
         */
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
            \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
        ) {
            $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
            $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        }
     public function afterGetList(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\FilterableAttributeList $subject, $collectionOld)
        {
         /** @var $collection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\Collection */
            $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
            $collection->setItemObjectClass(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::class)
                ->addStoreLabel($this->storeManager->getStore()->getId())
                ->setOrder('position', 'DESC');
            $collection = $this->_prepareAttributeCollection($collection);
            $collection->load();

            return $collection;
        }

      protected function _prepareAttributeCollection($collection)
      {
         $collection->addIsFilterableFilter();
         return $collection;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Where i create the plugin file? can you please give me the file name and path?

Comment: I am update answer . But this write in namespace + name class

Comment: you can create plugin file in a new Folder in module root named Plugin and file name will be FilterableAttributeList.php

Comment: Is this code is correct if i create this file in the plugin folder?

Comment: Yes, just then fix the namespace

Comment: can you please update the plugin file.I have changed the namespace but still not wroking.

Comment: Did you make `bin/magento s:d:c` ?

Comment: Please check the code for plugin here, https://www.mageplaza.com/how-use-plugin-preference-rewrite-block-model-controller-helper-magento-2.html. that is why i am asking to you the code of plugin file is right ?

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78819/discussion-between-sunny-rahevar-and-evgeniy-kapelko).