# Customer Login to Magento2 without triggering event 'customer_login'

Tags: magento2, customer-account, login

How to login a user with an E-mail to magento2 site without triggering event `customer_login`.

Actually, I am able to login with email using customer session but the customer session also triggers the `customer_login` events.

I don't want to use a trigger.

```
$customer = $this->_customer->loadByEmail("test@m2s.com"); 

$this->_customerSession->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
```

Comment: Can you please upload your full code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To modify any default functionality of magento you can simply override it's class.

Use [this reference](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/160047) to do the same.

In this case you have to override this method.

> Magento\Customer\Model\Session::setCustomerAsLoggedIn()

Remove the line from setCustomerAsLoggedIn() function which trigger 'customer_login' event.

```
 $this->_eventManager->dispatch('customer_login', ['customer' => $customer]);
```

Your function setCustomerAsLoggedIn will look like this.

```
 public function setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer)
{
    $this->setCustomer($customer);
    $this->_eventManager->dispatch('customer_data_object_login', ['customer' => $this->getCustomerDataObject()]);
    $this->regenerateId();
    return $this;
}
```

I hope it will helps you. And let me know if you need further help.